Moderator Nominations

If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. Moderator Pro Tempore


Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of chinese.stackexchange.com who:

Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

It's also good if the moderators:

Are members with participation in both meta.chinese.stackexchange.com and chinese.stackexchange.com.
Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.


More nominations guys!!! :D Don't be afraid to nominate yourself. If you have others in mind, nominate them! :D

Update: Moderators have been appointed.

xiaohouzi79, meta
He's been the most active until now, according to its stats and reputation, on the main site and he's been active on Meta as well. He has also other accounts so he's not new to the StackExchange mechanisms.

Alenanno, meta
 

Participates in the main site and meta
Is a prolific editor: show he cares about making the site look good
Is a moderator on Linguistics.SE, so has experience moderating SE sites


I'm Alenanno and I'm editing the answer as it is suggested above, first to accept the nomination in case the community shows support and I'm chosen consequently. Second to talk about myself, so you know something about me.
But before that, a small note: I saw my nomination earlier but I didn't know what to write yet so I waited. I didn't know because I was honestly (positively) surprised I already received a nomination; I'm glad for this support so thanks to everyone who will show that.
Now to my short description: As you might know already, by reading my profile on this site, I'm a student studying languages; I have a deep interest in languages, and that's why I'm learning some on my own. Chinese is one of them. The process is slow, but that was taken into account when I decided to study alone so I can live with it :) ...; even if slowly, I'm still progressing and this site will be a good help in my path to Chinese fluency. Also, as I already did, I'll help other people whenever my knowledge — alone or with the aid of external sources — will allow me to do that, and I hope that this site will continue to develop and attract new people and keep "old" ones. :)
I think that's enough for now, so if you have any questions about me, feel free to ask!

Huang, Meta
Huang is an extremely active member of the site, is (I'm presuming) a Chinese native speaker, and has provided valuable answers to a wide range of questions on the site. I think he would make a great moderator for Chinese.SE

Thanks for your recommendaton. I am not familiar with the site, though I can give you answers. I mean, I am not familiar with the moderator discipline and tools, so I think I am not suitable to work as a moderator.

Good, we need a moderator who doesn't use the tools too excessively.

@Village Editing is part of this site, I'm not doing anything weird, unlike you think, and actually it's encouraged. And remember that, if you don't like my edits, you can always rollback. :)

@Village: This is not a constructive qualification for moderators. You need moderators who are both familiar with the people issues involved in communities and willing and able to use the tools provided and apply them to those issues. Whether Huang is or is not up to that I have no idea, but his honest assessment that he isn't familiar with the discipline in general is probably a good place to start; the tools can usually be learned if you have the judgement as a person in the first place.

@Village: As for your apparent gripe with edits, please be aware that that all SE sites are community edited and the tools are not just provided to moderators, but all high-rep users. You want to elect people based on their judgement in handling exceptions, not their use or non use of "tools". If you are uncomfortable with the idea of people editing your content, per the site FAQ, SE might not be the place for you because its par for the course! If people are abusing these abilities you can always post on meta to make a case and a moderator (community exception handler!) will step in to help.

I am quite familiar with other Stack Exchange sites. I have no problem with people editing my posts on those sites, merging questions, closing them, etc. On other Stack Exchange sites, the reasons are always clear and justifiable. In fact, I often fix or delete my own questions after realizing they were not good, that I have made some mistake, or after having someone point out such facts. Go right ahead and make changes! Just please have a good reason to.

However, on this site, some moderators are doing too much pointless reorganizing of the whole site. A moderator is not a copy editors. This makes it really difficult for me (I can't speak for others) to keep track of posts. "Did I read that one? Oh, yes, I already did, but now it just has a new name." "How about this one?"

"A lot of the moderation work is extremely mundane, almost janitorial. It’s deleting obvious spam, closing blatantly off-topic questions, and culling some of the worst rated posts in various dimensions.
The ideal moderator does as little as possible. But those little actions may be powerful and highly concentrated. Judiciously limiting your use of moderator powers to selectively prune and guide the community — now that’s the true art of moderation." Source: A Theory of Moderation

@Village: FTR, this site is in beta. Editing, refining and re-organizing are encouraged by the community to set the tone, scope and standards the future site may be held to. Minior edits on beta sites are only discouraged when they are on old posts that shouldn't be needlessly bumped to the home page. Also your beef doesn't seem to be with moderators at all, the people and edits in question are community members and this involvement is to be encouraged. Editing is not a "moderator power", it's a community power. It has nothing to do with moderation and the bog post you quote doesn't apply.

Jon, meta
I know I'm new here, but I'm active in other stackexchange communities and thought I'd throw my hat into the ring. I have a great deal of interest in encouraging good answers which are useful and accessible to experts and language learners alike. I have already begun to promote chinese.stackexchange and am excited to make this site as helpful as possible.
I think I'll withdraw my nomination: I'd prefer to spend my time crafting questions and answers rather than dealing with flagged content. Plus, I like everyone else in the running, so I might as well leave this job to them.
